# SwiftUI - get default device user background colour

Tags: xcode, swiftui, tvos

So I know that we don't need to set the background colour of a view. however I have a fullscreen overview that shows with a transparent background colour I would like that color to be the default background colour of the device.

I am wondering in SwiftUI what is the code to request the `color.UIbackground`

This is for tvOS

Comment: Couple of options here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117455